# How to migrate aura:id to Lightning Web Components

Tags: aura, migration, lightning-web-components, aura-id

How do I migrate a

```
<div aura:id="foo"></div>
```

from `Aura` to `LWC` when I use Aura `Id` for finding?

```
cmp.find("foo");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the LWC docs to offload some of this to the MDN docs, so bringing this one layer higher (in the actual LWC docs would be nice) would have made it easier for us.

In scenarios where there are two components of the same type on your template, the equivalent to `aura:id` is to use a `data-id` tag and select it like this:

`this.template.querySelector('[data-id="userform"]')`

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent of using `aura:id` and `component.find()` in LWC is to use a standard DOM query selector like this:

```
const element = this.template.querySelector('selector');
element.doSomething();
```

We do have a restrictions to that standard behavior: you cannot use the `id` attribute as a selector as these are autogenerated by the framework.
You are free to use any tag name or CSS class to filter the element that you wish to retrieve.

See [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_javascript_methods).

Comment: Adding to this, if you want 1:1 equivalency, you can use `this.template.querySelector('[data-id="userform"]')`. This helps if there are multiple of the same component.

Comment: Thats worth its own answer.

Comment: Using a custom attribute will work but it has a performance impact. CSS attribute selectors don't perform that well so you may be better off by adding a class attribute (even if you don't use it for styling) and use it to discriminate the right component: `this.template.querySelector('.unique-class-name')`