# Lwc- problem to get id as it changes with random no. inside external Js

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, dom, lwc-dom

Hi all I am trying to access the id of a div in lwc  with the help external js(static resource) where code is like `document.getElementById("createsulightning");`
for `<div id="createsulightning"></div>` but when it renders in the community it shows `<div id="createsulightning-18">` with any random no.  so what changes need to be updated in js or html for working like situations . here is screenshot attached for inspecting element in chrome

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As inspired by the two answers to this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/250690/how-to-migrate-auraid-to-lightning-web-components), try using `this.template.querySelector()` on a `data-id` property that you define on the child, or any other selector property.

Answer (score 0):

No support for ID selectors in CSS. Make sure that id values are unique within your HTML template. When the template is rendered, id values may be transformed into globally unique values. If you use an ID selector in CSS, it won’t match the transformed ID
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_css