# LWC: Get Button Element in JavaScript from LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-dom

Scenario: I have a LWC with a `lightning-button` which calls an action in the JS controller. Within the JS controller, I am trying to target the button element and update it's innerHTML and/or update it to disabled=true.

---

**Per the Salesforce LWC Documentation "[Access Elements the Component Owns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_dom_work)":**

> To access elements rendered by a component, use the template property.
>
> this.template.querySelector();
>
> this.template.querySelectorAll();

**and per [How to migrate aura:id to Lightning Web Components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/250690/how-to-migrate-auraid-to-lightning-web-components,)** data-id acts as the LWC equivilent of aura:id from Aura components.

---

So, following that guidance, **I added a data-id to a lightning-button in my markup:**

```
<template if:true={showSendSignature}>
    <lightning-button name="Send for Signature" data-id="adobeSignBtn" variant="success" label="Send for Signature" onclick={adobeSendForSignature} ></lightning-button>  
</template>
```

**In my JavaScript, I then do:**

```
const adobeButton = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="adobeSignBtn"]');
console.log(adobeButton);
```

**When I inspect the page, I notice that the data-id is actually on a parent element to the button itself, rather than on the button element:**

```
<lightning-button c-alphacreateorderform_alphacreateorderform="" data-id="adobeSignBtn"
    <button name="Send for Signature" type="button" class="slds-button slds-button_success slds-button_first">Send for Signature</button>
</lightning-button>
```

In console, adobeButton returns `SecureElement: [object HTMLElement]`

When I do `console.log(adobeButton.childNodes)`, I get back `SecureNodeList: [object NodeList]`

However, when I do `adobeButton.childNodes[0]`, I get `undefined`

---

**Question:** How do I correctly access this button in a LWC JS controller?

Comment: Why not just use `event.target`?

Comment: event.target.value returns undefined, and event.target.setAttribute("disabled", true); does nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: `event.target.nodeName` returns `LIGHTNING-BUTTON`, `event.target.querySelector('button')` returns null, `event.target.childNodes.length` and `event.target.children.length` return 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [Event.target](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cLetQAE) will refer to the  element so you can do the following with them.

Access the `disabled` attribute directly:

```
const adobeButton = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="adobeSignBtn"]');
adobeButton.disabled = true;
```

```
handleButtonClick(event){
    event.target.disabled = true;
}
```

---

You're not just limited to the attributes, you can do more on the element like styles

```
const adobeButton = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="adobeSignBtn"]');
adobeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

```
handleButtonClick(event){
    event.target.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

---

You can also interact with the class of the element

```
const adobeButton = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="adobeSignBtn"]');
adobeButton.className += " slds-hide";
```

```
handleButtonClick(event){
    event.target.className += " slds-hide";
}
```

You can see this all of these in the following [playground](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/E6kEoLPuaKgIbYalbfNQ/).

Comment: Choosing this answer because it more correctly answers the core question "how to get Button element in JS Controller from LWC"

Comment: For completeness: is it possible to access any element property, such as style/class/name/id/etc directly in this way?

Answer (score 1):

I personally like to keep by button declarations in a property to avoid these kinds of "scenarios" and If I need to modify anything, I just need to do so in the JS file without having to modify the HTML template and can easily access its props and modify them.

Example:

```
export default class MyLwcWithJSButtonProps extends LightningElement {

    actionBtns = [{ label: 'a label', value: 'a value', disabled: false, class: 'if applicable', variant: 'if applicable', action: (e) => { this.handlerSomething(e) }}}]
    
    handlerSomething(e){
        
        const btn = e.detail.name;
        this.actionBtns - this.actionBtns.map( btn => { return {...btn, disabled:(some condition) ? true : false}})

    }
}
```

template

```
<template>
    <template for:each={actionButtons} for:item="btn">
            <lightning-button key={btn.value} variant={btn.variant} label={btn.label} title={btn.label} onclick={btn.action}
              class={btn.class} disabled={btn.disabled}></lightning-button>
          </template>
</template>
```